# await for subscribe angular

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-material

i need to await for a subscription and then assign that result to a particular variable in angular 7 but that code is not awaiting my code is like this.

```html
async getItemsbyId(id) {
console.log('2')
 await  this.stockService.getStocks(id).subscribe(
   (res: any) => {
   console.log('3')
    this.data = res.data;
    return this.data;
  },
  err => {
    console.log(err);
  },
  () => {
    this.http_item = null;
  }
);
console.log('4')
} 

get_value(){
console.log('1')
this.getItemsbyId(5);
console.log('5')
}
```

i need console to (1,2,3,4,5) in that order but i get (1,2,4,5,3) please provide a answer for this problem

Comment: function is not waiting for the stockservice response

Comment: Sadly, you can't await a subscription. You can only await promises.

Comment: You have two options. Either you do `toPromise()` instead of the subscribe ( not recommended), or you use a pipe with `tap()`, `catchError()` and `finalize()`instead of the subscribe, and return the resulting observable. Then you can subscribe inside `getValue` and do console log inside of that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const stocks = await this.stockService.getStocks(id).toPromise();
// DO STUFF this.data = stocks.data;
```